# How can I check a file signed with system key?

Tags: android, signature

How can I check a file, which is signed with system key (my key) or not?
I need to verify a file, which is downloaded from a server has been signed with (system key) my key for security reason?

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check the file in the run-time you may check the PackageInfo:

```
PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("<your.package.name>", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
    // check the signature here...
}
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo.html#signatures

Answer (score -1):

use this command, (go to java > jdk > bin path in cmd prompt) write the command

```
$ jarsigner -verify -verbose -certs my_application.apk
```

If you see "CN=Android Debug", this means the .apk was signed with the debug key generated by the Android SDK (means it is unsigned), else u will find something for CN. for more details 
go through this link
http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html